# How do you find an unknown point via the known location of other points and the angle of the unknown point when facing the known points?

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, coordinate-systems, triangulation

Based on this previous question, but slightly different:
[Find a point using multilateration or triangulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788306/find-a-point-using-multilateration-or-triangulation?newreg=ecd08f6a9ac1460db045ae2363b4bed6)

Suppose we have 3 points in a 3d coordinate system with the following locations.

A=(100,0,0) B=(0,100,100) C=(0,0,100)

If there is a 4th point, D, that has its angles known when pointed toward the other three points, can its location be found? If so, how would I find the coordinates? More known points can be added.

This is another similar question that has a useful picture that goes along with it: [How can I find the coord of the 4th point only by the known coords of the other three points and the angles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114921/how-can-i-find-the-coord-of-the-4th-point-only-by-the-known-coords-of-the-other)

This question has many answers, but it is in 2d: [Find 3rd point of triangle given two points and one angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500378/find-3rd-point-of-triangle-given-two-points-and-one-angle)
Would more points be needed for 3d?

Comment: What angles you are referring to? 1) $\angle ADX, \angle BDX, \angle CDX$ where $DX$ is pointing along a known (or unknown?) direction or 2) the 3 angles $\angle ADB, \angle BDC$, $\angle CDA$?

Comment: @achillehui Where DX is pointing along an unknown axis. It's consistent but isn't related directly to the points coordinate system. It's a problem I'm having with pointing a camera at some object in real life. I know the angles the camera is pointing at and the locations of the objects it's pointing at. Honestly, I've been thinking of ways to relate the unknown axis angles to a known axis, and I think I've come up with a way if only that is possible. (angle to A - angle to B is the angle between ADB or something)